# From where did the symbols *args and **kwargs in Python originate?

Tags: python

I know that `*args` and `**kwargs` are ways to feed more arguments into a function in Python.

I am wondering where these terms stem from. Why have all the asterisks in the beginning? What does the kw in kwargs stand for?

Comment: What part of http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions is confusing?  It seems very clear.  Can you provide the specific words or phrases that confuse you?

Comment: @S.Lott What part of the documentation touches on the origin of the notation?

Comment: "What does the kw in kwargs stand for?" seems to be quite clearly defined.  The "origin" for all of Python is either in a PEP (20%) or in the head of the BDFL (80%).

Comment: @root45: Please post your answer as an answer.

Comment: @S.Lott content update, the page you're linking doesn't mention at any point the string `kwargs` and only three times `args`, but in places where it doesn't answers the OP's question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "kw" stands for Key Word because the dictionary that you pass in is expanded to a sequence of key-word pair arguments. As to "Why have all the asterisks in the beginning?" I ask you, why not have them?

My hypothesis as to why the * characters were chosen is that they frequently have a wildcard meaning (e.g., in regular expressions or globing). This is just guess-work though and I have nothing to document that.

Comment: In C, they mean "pointer to", as in "indirect reference".  Maybe that's why they were chosen.